# write a test to pass/fail the number of items in a Navigation menu using Java and or Python

Tags: java, python, selenium, nav

So the issue i am having is that i am trying to count how many items(**there are 8)** are in the navigation menu of https://www.softrams.com/ and the logic won't pull through correctly. Either i am using the wrong function or i am not coding it correctly.

the code I built for this function is

```
WebElement nav_menu_count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'nav navbar-nav')]"));
    System.out.println(nav_menu_count.getSize());
    String nav_count = "710, 51";
    if(nav_menu_count.equals(nav_count))
    System.out.println("Menu count is correct");
    else
        System.out.println("Menu count is incorrect");
```

**my console output when i run this code is:**

> (710, 51) Menu count is incorrect

Comment: use driver.findElements instead (plural form) and store it in a List<WebElement>. Then use size() instead. getSize() will get you the top left corner of the first menu.

Comment: You can't use `equals()` to test whether a `WebElement` is equal to a `String`. That's comparing apples with watermelons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are selecting menu bar, and `getSize()` on single WebElement will return [width and height of the rendered element](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize--), not number of menu items.

Menu items have the following xpath:

```
//ul[contains(@class,'nav navbar-nav')]/li/a
```

Having that xpath, select all elements, like someone suggested in comments, and get count of those items:

```
List<WebElement> allMenuItems = driver.findElements(
                 By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'nav navbar-nav')]/li/a")); 
int count = allMenuItems.size(); // should return 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that need to be resolved:

1. Your locator is going to return the `UL` which is not the number of menu items but is instead the number of menus, which is 1. (NOTE: UL is an unorder list and LIs are the list items.) You want the count of LIs contained in the UL that you located.
2. You are using `.findElement()` which will either return a single element or throw an exception if the element is not found. You want `.findElements()` (notice the plural, in Element**s**) and then count the number of items in the returned collection.
3. You are comparing the count to a ??? String "710, 51"? I'm not sure what that is supposed to do. You instead want an `int`, 8.
4. `nav_menu_count.equals(nav_count)` is comparing a `WebElement` to a `String` which won't work.
5. Don't try to write your own validation library. Investigate JUnit or TestNG for Java and the equivalent for python, if you go that way. It will make your life a lot easier.

Now all that code is reduced to

```
List<WebElement> menus = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.nav > li"));
Assert.assertEquals(menus.size(), 8);
```